# No toolbar buttons when using SLVC_FULLSCREEN with REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY

Tags: toolbar, abap, alv

I have written ABAP program by SAP Press book **ABAP Basics listing 5.1**.

Everything is working fine except I am not able to display any icon for execute/delete operation which I added using `slvc_fullscreen` from `reuse_alv_grid_display`. I am not able to see even back button on the screen when I delete function. Any suggestions?

```
REPORT  ZPTB00_HOTEL_RESERVATION_COOL.
TYPE-POOLS slis.
* main menu as selection screen
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 110.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b110 WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-001.
PARAMETERS:
  p_add    TYPE c RADIOBUTTON GROUP grp1 DEFAULT 'X',
  p_delete TYPE c RADIOBUTTON GROUP grp1,
  p_show   TYPE c RADIOBUTTON GROUP grp1.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b110.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 110.

* input new reservation
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 120.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b120 WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-002.
PARAMETERS:
  p_room   TYPE zptb00_room_number VALUE CHECK,
  p_chkin  TYPE zptb00_check_in,
  p_chkout TYPE zptb00_check_out,
  p_name   TYPE zptb00_customer_name.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b120.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 120.

DO.
  CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 110.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    EXIT.
  ELSEIF p_add = 'X'.
    PERFORM zptb00_hrc_add.
  ELSEIF p_delete = 'X'.
    PERFORM zptb00_hrc_delete.
  ELSEIF p_show = 'X'.
    PERFORM zptb00_hrc_show.
  ENDIF.
ENDDO.

FORM zptb00_hrc_add.
  DATA: l_str_reservation TYPE  zptb00_hreservat,
        l_tab_reservation TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zptb00_hreservat.
* call input dailog
  CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 120 STARTING AT 5 5.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    SELECT * FROM zptb00_hreservat INTO TABLE l_tab_reservation
     WHERE ( room_number = p_room ) AND ( ( checkin BETWEEN p_chkin AND p_chkout ) OR ( checkout BETWEEN p_chkin AND p_chkout ) ).
    IF sy-dbcnt > 0.
      MESSAGE s000(zptb00_messages_alv).
    ELSE.
      CALL FUNCTION 'GUID_CREATE'
        IMPORTING
          ev_guid_32 = l_str_reservation-id.
          l_str_reservation-room_number = p_room.
          l_str_reservation-checkin = p_chkin.
          l_str_reservation-checkout = p_chkout.
          l_str_reservation-customername = p_name.
      INSERT zptb00_hreservat FROM l_str_reservation.
      MESSAGE s001(zptb00_messages_alv).
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.

FORM zptb00_hrc_delete.
  TYPES:
    BEGIN OF t_mark,
      mark TYPE c,
    END OF t_mark,
    BEGIN OF t_str_reservationx.
      INCLUDE STRUCTURE zptb00_hreservat.
      INCLUDE TYPE t_mark.
  TYPES:
    END OF t_str_reservationx.
  DATA:
    l_dis              TYPE disvariant,
    l_str_layout       TYPE slis_layout_alv,
    l_str_exit_by_user TYPE slis_exit_by_user,
    l_tab_reservationx TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_str_reservationx,
    l_str_reservationx TYPE t_str_reservationx,
    l_tab_reservation  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zptb00_hreservat,
    l_count            TYPE i.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS:
    <l_str_reservation>  TYPE zptb00_hreservat,
    <l_str_reservationx> TYPE t_str_reservationx.
  SELECT * FROM zptb00_hreservat INTO TABLE l_tab_reservation.
  LOOP AT l_tab_reservation ASSIGNING <l_str_reservation>.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING <l_str_reservation> TO l_str_reservationx.
    APPEND l_str_reservationx  TO l_tab_reservationx.
  ENDLOOP.
  l_str_layout-colwidth_optimize = 'X'.
  l_str_layout-window_titlebar = TEXT-003.
  l_str_layout-box_fieldname = 'MARK'.
  l_dis-report = sy-repid.

  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      i_callback_program       = l_dis-report
      i_callback_pf_status_set = 'CB_ALV_PF_SET_STATUS'
      i_callback_user_command  = 'CB_ALV_USER_COMMAND'
      i_structure_name         = 'ZPTB00_HRESERVAT'
      is_layout                = l_str_layout
      i_default                = 'X'
      i_save                   = 'A'
      is_variant               = l_dis
    IMPORTING
      es_exit_caused_by_user   = l_str_exit_by_user
    TABLES
      t_outtab                 = l_tab_reservationx
    EXCEPTIONS
      program_error            = 1
      OTHERS                   = 2.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
    WITH  sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.

  CASE 'X'.
    WHEN  l_str_exit_by_user-exit.
      LEAVE PROGRAM.
    WHEN l_str_exit_by_user-back OR l_str_exit_by_user-cancel.
      RETURN.
  ENDCASE.

  l_count = 0.
  LOOP AT l_tab_reservationx ASSIGNING <l_str_reservationx>.
    IF  <l_str_reservationx>-mark = 'X'.
      DELETE FROM zptb00_hreservat WHERE id = <l_str_reservationx>-id.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
  MESSAGE s002(zptb00_messages_alv) WITH l_count.
ENDFORM.  " zptb00_hrc_delete

FORM zptb00_hrc_show.
  DATA: l_dis             TYPE disvariant,
        l_rda_table       TYPE REF TO data,
        l_str_layout      TYPE slis_layout_alv,
        l_tab_reservation TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zptb00_hreservat.

  SELECT * FROM zptb00_hreservat INTO TABLE l_tab_reservation.
  l_str_layout-colwidth_optimize = 'X'.
  l_str_layout-window_titlebar = TEXT-004.
  l_dis-report = sy-repid.
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      i_structure_name = 'zptb00_hreservat'
      is_layout        = l_str_layout
      i_save           = 'A'
      is_variant       = l_dis
    TABLES
      t_outtab         = l_tab_reservation
    EXCEPTIONS
      program_error    = 1
      OTHERS           = 2.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
    WITH  sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.

FORM cb_alv_user_command USING r_ucomm LIKE sy-ucomm
  rs_selfield TYPE slis_selfield.
  IF r_ucomm = 'EXECUTE'.
    rs_selfield-exit = 'X'.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.

FORM cb_alv_pf_status USING rt_extab TYPE slis_t_extab.
  SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN' EXCLUDING rt_extab.
ENDFORM.
```

[image: screenshot of delete operation]

Comment: You have to format you code.

Comment: Does your program have a status names STANDARD_FULLSCREEN?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'm right but in the '**zptb00_hrc_delete**' form in the '**REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**' function you set:

```
I_CALLBACK_PF_STATUS_SET = 'CB_ALV_PF_SET_STATUS'
```

However the '**CB_ALV_PF_SET_STATUS**' form doesn't exist. I think you misspelled the name of the form because there's a form called '**CB_ALV_PF_STATUS**' that seems to fit:

```
FORM cb_alv_pf_status USING rt_extab TYPE slis_t_extab.
  SET pf-status 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN' EXCLUDING rt_extab.
ENDFORM.
```

Let's try changing that in the '**REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**' call like this:

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      I_CALLBACK_PROGRAM       = l_dis-report

      I_CALLBACK_PF_STATUS_SET = 'CB_ALV_PF_STATUS' " ---> 'CB_ALV_PF_SET_STATUS' replaced by 'CB_ALV_PF_STATUS'

      I_CALLBACK_USER_COMMAND  = 'CB_ALV_USER_COMMAND'
      I_STRUCTURE_NAME         = 'ZPTB00_HRESERVAT'
      IS_LAYOUT                = l_str_layout
      I_DEFAULT                = 'X'
      I_SAVE                   = 'A'
      IS_VARIANT               = l_dis
    IMPORTING
      ES_EXIT_CAUSED_BY_USER   = l_str_exit_by_user
    TABLES
      T_OUTTAB                 = l_tab_reservationx
    EXCEPTIONS
      PROGRAM_ERROR            = 1
      OTHERS                   = 2.
```

> I'm assuming that '**STANDARD_FULLSCREEN**' GUI status exists. Check
>   that please.

Another observation is that in the form '**zptb00_hrc_show**' you are you using lowercase in the  '**i_structure_name**' parameter in function '**REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**' but it should be uppercase.

Instead of:

```
i_structure_name = 'zptb00_hreservat'
```

It should be:

```
i_structure_name = 'ZPTB00_HRESERVAT'
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In your line 161 you set:

```
SET pf-status 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN' EXCLUDING rt_extab.
```

nmiranda assume that 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN' GUI status exists. I assume it does not exist.

Can you open your report with SE38, display the code ad make a double click on `STANDARD_FULLSCREEN`. If you get a warning, that the status does not exist you identified the problem.

If the status exist: Did you define a button for delete?

If no -> define one. If you don't know how to do it, please post a comment. I will check if I can make a screenshot (sorry, actual I have no SAP available).

If you defined a button, please check i debugger the content of table `rt_extab`. If it contains the user command of your delete-action, then the button is suppressed. (I found nothing in your code, that fills the table, just to be sure).